# How to dynamically retrieve and make assertions of the responses from Rest ReadyAPI request

Tags: rest, groovy, automation, soapui, ready-api

I'm new in readyAPI but not in rest API services.
I created the data driven automation in ReadyAPI.
I properly imported all the fields from excel file to the "DataSource" test step where the "DataSource Loop" iterates over it and loads the "REST Request" test step sending many different payloads over the same end point.
Naturally, I want to make the assertions on every response from the iteration, not on the last one only.
By default, ReadyAPI overwrites all the responses from previous iterations, so you have the last one only stored in the tool.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes that is correct. And what is your question? If you want to see all the requests/responses you can run the command-line version, and ask it to dump out all requests: `testrunner.sh -A your.project.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

even though you can only 'see' the last response and assertion, you know they been checked.  Have to be careful though as you can set a test to stop or fail or simply carry on.

When executing a long-running test that I don't want to stop on fail, I dump out the results for each call using Data Sink.

So, inside your loop, you can create a Datasink step.  It's like the opposite of Data Source step, but you can write out data.

When using these, I tend not to use assertions.  I prefer to use a Groovy step to perform some boolean check and then write the result to the Data Sink.